# Asus X552V - Cannot Boot from USB

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I want to install windows 7 from USB, but when I go in bios I do not have a boot from usb option. My notebook is Asus X552V. Where might I find the option in the BIOS menu for this? How can I boot from USB on this laptop?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you see under the "Boot" menu?

Comment: I have Fast Boot disabled. Launch CSM I cant with it anything doing. Boot Option Priorities . Boot Option # 1 (Windows Boot Manage ..). Add New Boot Option. Delete Boot Option. Can I with it anything doing ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting add a new boot option?

Also here is a link to Asus's site on how to boot the system over USB

https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1008277

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way:

1. You need to go to "Security" tab, set "Source boot control" to "Disable"
2. Then got back to "Boot" tab, you'll see "Launch CSM" to be settable. Please set it "Enable". Also set its sub-section "Launch PEX OpROM" "enalbe"
3. Save & Exit
4. Now you enter BIOS, you'll see USB device available in Boot option.